# Can't "make" older version of ImageMagick

Tags: linux-mint, make, imagemagick

I need to install a 6.9 version of ImageMagick for an older Rails app which I maintain (which uses Ruby 1.8.6 in an RVM).

This is in a new install of Linux Mint 18.

I downloaded a "ImageMagick-6.9.6-7.tar.gz" file, unzipped it, went into the resulting folder and tried to build it.

There was a lot of output from the `./configure` step but it seemed happy enough.  However, `make` is failing with lots of output: there's tons of stuff like this:

```
coders/png.c: In function ‘ReadOnePNGImage’:
coders/png.c:2238:45: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘png_set_keep_unknown_chunks’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
        png_set_keep_unknown_chunks(ping, 1, mng_iCCP, 1);
                                             ^
In file included from /usr/include/libpng12/png.h:321:0,
                 from coders/png.c:101:
/usr/include/libpng12/png.h:2330:25: note: expected ‘png_bytep {aka unsigned char *}’ but argument is of type ‘const png_byte * {aka const unsigned char *}’
 extern PNG_EXPORT(void, png_set_keep_unknown_chunks) PNGARG((png_structp
```

etc.

Since this is a new install I suspect I might be missing some build tool or dev utils or something.  Can anyone help?  Sorry if this is a bit vague.

EDIT:  A full list of the packages I have installed: http://pastebin.com/bJg4qC0M

EDIT 2: full output from `make`:  http://pastebin.com/qXu5FUC4

EDIT 3: output from `make install`: http://pastebin.com/5TPeQScp

Comment: Can you post the full output of `make`?  A link to a pastebin or github gist is fine.

Comment: yep, will do, just running it again...done

Comment: It looks to me like `make` finished successfully.  What's the exit code of `make`? If it's 0, everything compiled successfully and you can install with `make install`.

Comment: How do I find out the exit code?  I don't think it worked - see EDIT 3

Comment: Immediately after make completes, in the same shell as where you ran make, run `echo $?` to get the exit code.  `make install` didn't work because you don't have permissions to install to the destination folder (look carefully at the output `make install` ;).  You can change the destination folder by using the `--prefix=/path/to/destination` argument to `./configure`, or you can temporarily chown the destination (in this case `/usr/local/` as well as sub folders such as `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/local/lib`, etc.) to your user and then back to root after you're done.

Comment: ah - so i just need to sudo everything!  I think I knew that, and forgot.  Will try again...

Comment: Yep, i think that worked, with sudo.  Doh. : `convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2016-11-29 http://www.imagemagick.org`

Comment: No, DON'T sudo everything. For instance, it's usually a bad idea to run `make install` with sudo, for several reasons: 1) `make` can run anything; you have no idea what it will do or where it will place files, and you just gave an unknown script root privileges; 2) even if `make install` is well behaved, now you have unmanaged files that are installed to areas normally managed by a package manager; 3) it's next to impossible to undo completely, even if `make uninstall` is available.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the actual *error* message (the thing you mentioned in the question is a *warning*, which will not terminate the compilation process):

> libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c magick/.libs/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.2.0.0 /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.2.0.0
>   /usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.2.0.0': Permission denied

This means that when you ran `make install`, you did so as a user who does not have permission to create files in the `/usr/local/lib` directory.

There's a couple of solutions to this.

The shoot-yourself-in-the-foot-solution is to run `sudo make install`.  This is bad because

1. You don't know what the Makefile does when you run `make install`, and in the worst case scenario, you may execute malicious code as `root`.
2. Installing things into `/usr/local` on a Linux system (or any Unix system) is bad because that's usually a location where files are installed by various package managers. This means that you may run the risk of overwriting existing files.
3. How do you plan to uninstall the software?

A couple of better solutions:

1. Configure the project to install in a neutral environment, such as `/opt` or `/sw` (wherever is unused by the system and package manager). Do this by running `configure` with the `--prefix` option, for example `./configure --prefix=/opt`. Notice that this may still require you to run `sudo make install` unless you have write permissions in the installation hierarchy.
2. Configure the project to install somewhere under our home directory. This may be the best option if you don't need to install the thing system-wide. Just do as above, but set the installation prefix to something like `$HOME/local`, or even `$HOME/tmp` (and then just remove that directory when you're done with it).

The first of these approaches don't entirely solve the problem of later uninstalling the software, and the second approach solves it only if installing into an otherwise empty hierarchy (just `rm -rf` the whole thing). For that, I can recommend the [GNU Stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) utility. This makes it easier to uninstall software that you're building yourself. Without it, it's really difficult to track down what files has to be removed if you wish to uninstall something.